# Calculating Minimum Lectures required for a target attendance %

Tags: javascript

The concept is simple,
Suppose I have attended 3 out of 4 lectures. My current % would be 75%
I want the % above 95. This means I need to attend 16 more classes to make it 19 out of 20 lectures.

This is what I have implemented in JS. I needed to multiply 10 at the end - not sure why the answer was coming 1/10th of the correct answer.

```js
var present=3, absent=1;
var total = present+absent;
var CurrentPercentage = (100*present)/total;

var classReq = (95 * total)/100 - present;
classReq += (95 * classReq)/100;

console.log(classReq>0?(Math.ceil(classReq*10)):0);
```

It works but I think there must be a better algorithm (I am sure there must be)

Comment: you provided code that already works and didn't ask a question. maybe you mean to post this in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew about it.

Comment: So basically, the question you're asking is: Given number of absences `x`, what is the smallest possible fraction that is above target percentage `y` (in this case, 95%). Since you've only missed one class, 19/20 works, but if you'd skipped 2 already, you'd need 40 class sessions to hit 38/40

Comment: Yes. I need that number which on addition to my current lectures attended makes it 38 out of 40 to get 95% attendance.

Comment: This question should be moved to the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have a count of lecture (20) and a percent value (95%) and visited lecture (3), you could calculate the missing count and subtract the already visited lectures.

```js
var target = 95,
    lectures = 20,
    visited = 3,
    needed = lectures * target / 100 - visited;

console.log(needed);
```

You could have a look to the missed lectures, then you could calculate the needed lectures.

```js
var target = 95,  // percent
    visited = 3,
    missed = 1,   // this is 5%
    needed = missed * 100 / (100 - target) - visited;

console.log(needed);
```

Comment: But we don't know the total number of classes. Sorry to not mention that. Ah, this way it would be simple. :D

Comment: but you need a base, for getting a count of lectures.

Comment: @Jonasw should I what explain this? or are you telling ^Nina Scholz

Comment: you need a value for 100%. In this case, you mentioned `20`. this value scales the result.

Comment: You are correct. But this is not the solution I want. You are totally correct. But in your case you have assumed 20 as total classes. What I want is, attendance should be 95% - and the final is not known until we know the classes required - which can be any number. I guess, I am not able to explain myself clearly. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AbhishekPathak, please have a look to the second proposal.

Comment: Thanks This is what I wanted. You are genius.

Comment: Hey, can you explain the logic. I need to know how you got this. It's to the point.

Comment: it is the question of the relation between `missed` to 5%, or the value of 1 to 5%. we need to calculate 100% if we know, that 5% is equal to 1. the formular is count * 100 / percent value. the result is the equivalent of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
current=3;
max=4;
if(current/max>0.95){
 alert("reached");
}else{
  Alert((0.95-current/max)*100+"% needed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It's not what I want. The max value is what I don't know. It will increase with the classes. Say, I have attended 10 classes and missed 1, so I need to attend 9 more for my attendance percentage to be greater than 95%. Here, the problem is varying total class, which will change with the classes attended and classes required.